# Django web bash

Tags: django, linux, bash, shell

***_*____** I have a Django website on my Linux server.

**Goal** :  i want to make web jquery shell/bash of my Linux server , where my site is located , so i could directly from web site pass commands to linux and get all the outputs ,etc.

***Questions***

**Question 1**: I know about new subprocess module and popen class , haven't tried it yet , but surely will but right now i experimented with os module. So why os.popen('ls -l') works , but os.open('ls -l >> somefile.txt') doesn't.

**Questions 2**: i know that when you use screen command somewhere in some file everything that is done is written to a file . Any idea where and what file it is ? Or which file contains everything that is output to bash ?

**I am pretty sure** that once i come home and try some more :D i will have much more concrete questions but for now that is all... Any suggestions or pointers where i should go , what i should read are appreciated.  Thx in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a huge security hole waiting to happen. Make sure you know what you're doing!

Comment: Write a script that takes a command in the http request, executes it with bash, and returns the stderr/stdout in the response. Think simple first.

Comment: Ofcourse it's not for users. Only for admin panel . So unless somebody figures out how to access my admin panel everything should be okay, otherwise even without this hole but with admin panel access theres a lot damage you can do =). But for now i don't care about security , just want to make it for my own satisfaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well i found an answer myself.**

Didn't magically code it yet , but soon will .
So as we all know we have a Linux command  **screen**. This command can make logs of everything that is happening in your screen , by pushing "ctrl-A H" , who uses it knows. But the problem is, that logs  are not written immediately , so it doesn't help much . But **screen** command has also another interesting command called hardcopy , which basically forcefully dumps all screen content copy to a file , where from you'll be able to get result as soon as you'll type it.

I maybe be not accurate and right about explanations of commands , but generally it works like this .

**Security**

I am in no way Linux expert , and haven't done it yet , but as much as i understand person is logged as user in a screen session , unless he knows root login and password or is super mega hacker which can obtain it, there is basically nothing he can do to destroy the system.

Comment: If you wanted to use screen, you would have to implement the NCURSES commands inside your web shell.

Comment: First time hearing about it . Thanks , seems like an interesting library . Will look into it .

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to change SSH to web interface of terminal? I would not do that... You have amazing stuff called SSH and which allows you to perform even complex commands securely. I don't believe that you will manage to finish your "webterminal" with the same functionality. But you never know :) Think about transferring files though it, also security (how you will encode the input you will send, or you will just send it as a plain text? Of course https  could help here also). I think you will have a lot of fun :)

P.S. I know this post isn't very helpful, but just wanted to make sure if you're not trying to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Well lets say i am not a proffesional in that kind of stuff. sure i know about ssh .  And yes maybe :D i am reinventing the wheel in some point and i will not succeed with the same functionality and security. Still at one point i think its a good idea to try , yet gain some extra experience. Right now i don't care about security , as it is pretty complex and i will think about it later. For now all i need from somefile in linux get all content , pass commands and get results .